# updating hist2d plot via ipywidgets.interact is not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter, ipywidgets

Edit: I put in the required dataframe so that the issue is reproducible.

Sorry for the long excerpt of code, this is what I have on jupyter.
You can scroll to the very bottom and look for `draw_plots()` which works fine, and draws a matrix of `hist2d` s.
Later as you can see I run `modify_color('Hc', 'q', 0, 30)`, that also works fine and modifies the corresponding plot and its colormap update with the new limits given `(0-30)`.
Problem is: the last line, when I try to run `modify_color` through interactive widgets, it appears to run fine, I get good print statements which I put for debugging, but the plot and the colorbar do not update.

How can I get the plot and its colorbar to update?

```
merged =pd.DataFrame( {'Hc': {10000: 45.0,
  10001: 68.0,
  10002: 70.0,
  10003: 58.0,
  10004: 40.0,
  10005: 40.0,
  10006: 51.0,
  10007: 70.0,
  10008: 69.0,
  10009: 70.0},
 'SONUCNO': {10000: 1.0,
  10001: 2.0,
  10002: 3.0,
  10003: 4.0,
  10004: 5.0,
  10005: 6.0,
  10006: 7.0,
  10007: 8.0,
  10008: 9.0,
  10009: 10.0},
 'SONUCNORM': {10000: 0.07692307692307693,
  10001: 0.15384615384615385,
  10002: 0.2307692307692308,
  10003: 0.3076923076923077,
  10004: 0.38461538461538464,
  10005: 0.4615384615384616,
  10006: 0.5384615384615384,
  10007: 0.6153846153846154,
  10008: 0.6923076923076923,
  10009: 0.7692307692307693},
 'n_HJPair': {10000: 3,
  10001: 0,
  10002: 2,
  10003: 0,
  10004: 4,
  10005: 0,
  10006: 0,
  10007: 2,
  10008: 0,
  10009: 0},
 'q': {10000: 0.029980572858854998,
  10001: 0.13087877831873412,
  10002: 0.13350577945847913,
  10003: 0.1865475118001965,
  10004: 0.2053608670014144,
  10005: 0.24318638969823925,
  10006: 0.3040225082331678,
  10007: 0.459925865474959,
  10008: 0.5381321066914233,
  10009: 0.5919278296001834}})
from ipywidgets import interact
inp = ['Hc', 'n_HJPair']
out = ['SONUCNO', 'SONUCNORM', 'q']
global axs
global h2d
def draw_plots(in_props=inp, out_props=out):
  global axs
  global h2d


  n_in = len(in_props)
  n_out = len(out_props)
  h2d={}
  %matplotlib inline
  plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10*n_out, 5*n_in]
  fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=n_in,ncols=n_out)
  for index,inprop in enumerate(in_props):
    for index_2, outprop in enumerate(out_props):
      mask = (~((merged[inprop].isna()) | (merged[outprop].isna()))) 
      v_max = mask.sum()/40/20*5

      h2d[inprop+outprop] = (axs[index, index_2].hist2d(merged[mask][inprop],merged[mask][outprop], vmin=00, vmax=v_max, bins=[45,15], cmap='gist_rainbow'))
      axs[index, index_2].set_xlabel(inprop)
      axs[index, index_2].set_ylabel(outprop)
      fig.colorbar(h2d[inprop+outprop][3], ax=axs[index, index_2])

draw_plots()
def modify_color(ip,op,min=0,max=0):
  global h2d
  print("I am running with: ",ip,op,min,max)
  h2d[ip+op][3].set_clim(min,max)

modify_color('Hc', 'q', 0, 30)
interact(modify_color, ip=inp,op=out,min=0.0,max=100.0)
```

Comment: I get NameError: `merged` is not defined. Can you provide this data.

Comment: @ac24, I updated the code and put in merged.

Comment: This example needs to be simplified quite a lot, it's really too dense to figure out what is going on. All I can say is you definitely need a `draw_plots` function call in your `modify_color` function, otherwise this will never get triggered as you change the widget values. Can you simplify it down, or better still, build up from a very simple matplotlib chart that you *know* works with interact?